# Can't add swap file on solaris

Tags: solaris, swap

I'm trying to add a swap file on Solaris 10. I have already created a 2GB file `swap.file`. Then, I add a swap file with the command:

```
swap -a /swap.file
```

which shows an error:

> /swap.file: size is invalid

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5):

You are likely running a 32 bit kernel. You can just create 2 x 1 GB swap files and add them separately.

```
# rm /swap.file
# /usr/sbin/mkfile 1024m /swap1
# /usr/sbin/mkfile 1024m /swap2
# /usr/sbin/swap -a /swap1
# /usr/sbin/swap -a /swap2
```

Also, for this setting to survive a reboot, you'll also need to add lines to the /etc/vfstab file, eg:

```
/swap1 - - swap - no -
/swap2 - - swap - no -
```